# Does Natural deduction follow contradiction

Tags: logic

If I have

> $\sum \vdash_{ND} \implies a $

Can I say:

> $\sum, \neg a \vdash_{ND} \text{Contradiction}$

? Does it work like this?

Comment: Assuming your proof system is complete, yes. Without knowing if it is complete, it depends on the exact rules defined in the system, and $ND$ merely says 'Natural Deduction', and there are *many* different Natural Deduction systems, each with their own set of rules. So: what rules are given to you?

Comment: @Bram28, yes, this natural deduction is sound and complete

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the system $ND$ you are working with is sound and complete, then from $\Gamma \vdash_{ND} a$ you can conclude $\Gamma, \neg a \vdash_{ND} \bot$, since:

If $\Gamma \vdash_{ND} a$ then by soundness we have that $\Gamma \vDash a$, meaning that for any valuation $v$: if $v$ sets all statements in $\Gamma$ to true, then $v$ will set $a$ to true. But that means that it is impossible for there to be a valuation that sets all statements in $\Gamma$ to true as well as setting $\neg a$ to True, and hence all $0$ valuations that do set all statements in $\Gamma$ to true as well as setting $\neg a$ to True will also set $\bot$ to True. Hence: $\Gamma, \neg a \vDash \bot$. So by completeness $\Gamma, \neg a \vdash_{ND} \bot$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\Sigma \vdash_{ND} a$; let this proof be $P$ (form depends on ND-system).

Then to see $\Sigma , \lnot a \vdash \bot$ (where $\bot$ is the symbol for contradiction, usually):

Follow the proof $P$ to its conclusion $a$. This uses assumptions from $\Sigma$.
Then use the assumption $\lnot a$. Now there should be a rule in your ND system that concludes $\bot$ from $a$ and $\lnot a$. E.g. $a \land \lnot a$, which can now be proved is often replaced by $\bot$.