# Show a natural deduction proof exists

Tags: logic

> Prove for any set of formulas $\sum$ and any propositional formulas $p, q$. If $\sum \vdash_{ND} p$ then $\sum \vdash_{ND} ((\neg p) \implies q)$

$\sum \vdash_{ND} p \implies \sum, \neg p \vdash_{ND} \text{Contradiction}$

We have to show

$\sum \vdash_{ND} ((\neg p) \implies q)$ meaning $\sum \vdash_{ND},  ((\neg p) \implies q)$

Any idea how I can proceed?

Comment: If you can assume $ND$ is sound and complete, then take a good look at how I answered your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373763/does-natural-deduction-follow-contradiction/2373769#2373769 ... you should follow a similar pattern for this one as well.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\sum, \neg p \vdash_{ND} \bot$. Now, to prove that $\sum \vdash_{ND} (\neg p \Rightarrow q)$, using the the implication introduction rule(it is the deduction theorem) you need prove that $\sum, \neg p \vdash_{ND} q$, but $\sum, \neg p \vdash_{ND} \bot$ and consequently $q$.